# Memory deallocation about list of stacks

Tags: c++11

I've created a list of stacks.

```
using namespace std;
list<stack<int>> stacks;
stack<int> *st = new stack<int>();      //LINE0
stacks.push_back(*st);
st->push(10);   
stack<int> *last = &stacks.back();
stacks.pop_back();    //LINE1
delete last;          //LINE2
```

`LINE2` will cause an `unhandled exception`. Will `LINE1` automatically deallocate the memory allocated at `LINE0`? Is `LINE2` not necessary?

Comment: `list<stack<int>> stacks = new list<stack<int>>();` - that is not how you create a list of stacks in C++. You don't need `new` unless you need a pointer to a thing rather than just the thing itself. If you want a list of stacks, that's just `list<stack<int>> stacks;`.

Comment: There's no reason to use `new` in this code. C++ is not Java, Stop using `new`. The line `stacks.push_back(*st);` dereferences a pointer and stores a __copy__ of that object into `stacks`, `st` now points to a different object. The `delete last;` tries to delete an object that wasn't created using `new`. You need to [read a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and stop using `new`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, `stacks` contains objects, not pointers, and none of them were created by you using `new`. So the line `delete last;` is an error because you are giving it an address that wasn't received from `new`.

The key here is that `stacks.push_back(*st);` stores in the list a **copy** of the object pointed to by `st`.

On the other hand, `st` does contain a pointer received from a `new` expression. You should do a `delete st;` otherwise you will leak that memory.

Manual resource management can be error prone and difficult to reason about so I suggest you simply stop using `new` unless and until it's really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, containers delete stored object automatically.

C++ containers store exactly the type of data which is set as parameter. In this case list stores `stack<int>`, not pointer or reference to it. It means that container creates copy of object when `push_back` is running.

If you want store pointers in container, you should inform compiler about it:

```
list<stack<int>*>
```

That list won't delete stacks. It will delete pointers only.

By the way, I don't recommend to abuse allocating memory dynamically. It often leads to memory leaks.

Comment: If I use list<stack<int>*>, will the list delete the pointer itself? I do not need to delete the pointer? For example: list<stack<int>*> stacks;
stack<int> *st = new stack<int>();      //LINE0
stacks.push_back(st);
st->push(10);   
stack<int> *last = stacks.back();
stacks.pop_back();    //LINE1
delete last;          //LINE2. Do I need to use "delete last" to release the memory?

Comment: @John: You need to pause for a moment and understand what `stacks.push_back(*st);` is doing. Oh, and stop using `new` (so you won't need to use `delete` in the first place).

Comment: If I declare `stack<int> *st = new stack<int>();`, and `stacks.push_back(st);`, do I need to `delete st;`? or will `stacks.pop_back();` release the memory automatically?

Comment: @John: That won't compile because `stacks` holds objects and you can't push_back a pointer instead. Simply declare it as `stack<int> st;` and it will be automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope. No `new` or `delete` required. The elements in `stacks` will also be automatically cleaned up when you do `pop_back()`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Forgot to mention that I will define `list<stack<int>*> stacks;`. Then do `stack<int> *st = new stack<int>();`, and `stacks.push_back(st);`.

Comment: @John Yes, you need to delete object which you created by `new` but you didn't do that. At the moment you delete copy of this object which is created by the list in method `push_back`. After that `pop_back` is trying to delete this object again, and it is the cause of the error.

Comment: @John: Eeek, you might want to update this question or post a new one with your __actual code__. This has changed too much from what was originally posted.

Comment: +1, this answer is correct. I'm not sure why there is a down-vote, but it could be confusion between "deleting" something, and calling `delete` on a pointer to delete something else.